# Does anybody perhaps have IEC nc, no, and co switches for Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I refer to E1218 to E1220 and need better symbols for them with the following improvements:

- the moving slider needs to be the same length;
- the co needs to be symmetrical like E1224;
- we will need to add the contact modifiers later - especially E1229-E1232;
- we also need to be able to add mechanical properties to the slider.

Note that the slider should always move clockwise when operated.

I also attach the [IEC symbol reference](https://www.slideshare.net/vamsinimmakayala/iec-symbol-reference) noting it is a very old version.

[image]

[image]

Here is some hacked code checking the alignment of the current switch symbols:

[image]

```
    \begin{circuitikz}
    { % 
    \coordinate (a) at (-1,0);
    \draw (a)
%   node {X}%debug
    ++(-1,-0.25) node [anchor=east] {$U_n$} 
    to[short, o-] 
    ++(1,0)
    ++(-1,1.25) node [anchor=east] {$U_c$} 
    to[short, o-]
    ++(1,0)
    ++(-1,1) node [anchor=east] {$U_b$} 
    to[short, o-]
    ++(1,0)
    ++(-1,1) node [anchor=east] {$U_a$} 
    to[short, o-]
    ++(1,0);
    }
    \draw (-1,1) -- (-1,0.25);
    \draw (0.00,+0.25) to[nos,l=$\ $, ] ++(-1,0);
    \draw (0.00,-0.0)node[ocirc]{} to[nos,l=$\ $, ] ++(-1,0);
    \draw (-0.05,-0.25) to[ncs,l=$\ $,mirror, ] ++(-1,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
```

I have now done a crude design that will serve my needs for now - not close to final code.

```
{% no nc co switch
\coordinate (a) at (-0,01);
\draw (a)
node {x}%debug
to[short, -o] ++(-0.25,0);%fixed contact
{%
\draw[thick]($(a)+(-0.25,0)$) -- ++(-0.5,-0.225);%nc wiper
\draw ($(a)+(-0.75,-0.225)$) -- ++(-0.045,0.11);%early
\draw ($(a)+(-0.75,-0.225)$) -- ++(+0.045,-0.11);%late
}
{%
\draw[thick]($(a)+(-0.25,0)$) -- ++(-0.55,+0.05);%centre nc wiper
\draw ($(a)+(-0.8,+0.05)$) -- ++(0.01,0.11);%early
\draw ($(a)+(-0.8,+0.05)$) -- ++(-0.01,-0.11);%late
}
{%
\draw[thick]($(a)+(-0.25,0)$) -- ++(-0.5,-0.25);%no wiper
\draw ($(a)+(-0.75,-0.25)$) -- ++(-0.045,0.11);%early
\draw ($(a)+(-0.75,-0.25)$) -- ++(+0.045,-0.11);%late
}
\draw (a) ++(-0.625,-0.125) |- ++(-0.375,-0.125);%nc contact 
\draw (a) ++(-0.625,0.125) |- ++(-0.375,-0.125);%centre nc contact 
\draw(a) ++(-1,+0.25) -- ++(0.275,0);%no contact
\draw(a) ++(-1,+0) -- ++(0.25,0);%centre no contact
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please update the link to a more recent IEC document.

Comment: That looks like a lot of work.  You might find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365065/new-switches-in-circuitikz-no-nc/365308?r=SearchResults&s=3|38.8491#365308 useful.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Well, I am just asking if it was done... I only need three at the moment.  Btw. I also think E1236 is incorrectly drawn.

Comment: Uf. The switch in the package `circuitikz` are more of the "electronic" style, and these are the "electric" style ones. I can't say it can't be done (definitely easier than the recent IEEE gates), given that the number of in and out seems fixed, but I have not time now... Maybe if you do an enhancement request on https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues, with modern references someone will take up the task...

Comment: Look for example at the enhancement request by jason-s here: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/383